# Return zero or positive number?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I was initially thinking that the code below would return 0, my question, is there a function that I can use to only receive zero/positive results here?

```
NSUInteger pruneSize = 5 - 20; // Returns: -15
```

Currently I am just checking the result myself, but was wondering if I was missing something simpler.

```
NSUInteger pruneSize = 5 - 20;
if(pruneSize >= 0) {
    // Do zero/positive Stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pruneSize >= 0` is always true as `pruneSize` is unsigned. You should get a warning here. You need to change the type to `NSInteger`, that is the signed integer. If you want to clip the lower value to zero for a signed int then you can do this:

```
NSInteger pruneSize = 5 - 20; // signed int
pruneSize = pruneSize < 0 ? 0 : pruneSize;
```

Comment: Yes it did give a warning, I had not typed it into Xcode only typed it in here. I will change the type to NSInteger and do the comparison. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `abs(pruneSize)` which will return you positive or zero number in any case.

**EDIT:**

```
NSUInteger pruneSize = 5-20;
if(pruneSize < 0)
{
     pruneSize = 0;
}
NSLog(@"%d",pruneSize);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was too clear. What I wanted was for negative results to return zero i.e. 5-20=0, 5-15=0, 7-2=5 etc. ABS in the original case would return positive 15.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your function to return always zero if your result is in negative(less than 0) then return zero or else return result

```
int n=0;
if(result > 0){ //positive
   n = result
else
   n = 0
return n
```

or use the abs method